# How to deselect / dehighlight multiple items using QGraphicsScene::clearSelection()?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

I have a `QGraphicsScene` which has 100+ items. Sometimes I need to highlight and dehighlight multiple items.

Here is the code:

```
HighlightObject(QEvent* event)
{
   //Finding object under cursor
   QMouseEvent* mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
   QPointF mousePoint = _view->mapToScene(mouseEvent->pos());
   QGraphicsItem* itemUnderClick = scene->itemAt(mousePoint, QTransform());
   
   QGraphicsPathItem* polylineItem = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsPathItem*>(itemUnderClick);
    if (polylineItem ) {
        //polylineItem ->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);//I have set this flag while drawing polyline.
        polylineItem ->setSelected(true);
        QPen mPen(Qt::SolidLine);
        mPen.setWidth(1);
        polylineItem ->setPen(mPen);
      }
}
```

My scene has 1 button which refreshes the scene. (which dehighlight all the items in the scene)

```
 Refresh()
   {
      foreach (QGraphicsItem* currentItem, scene->items()) 
     {
       myPoly* pItem = qgraphicsitem_cast<myPoly*>(currentItem);
       if (pItem)  
       {
           pItem->setSelected(false);
           pItem->setPen(QPen(QColor("red")); // original color of polyline is red.
       }
    }
```

Above code works fine. But my `scene` has many elements so this Refresh() becomes costly.
So in Refresh() I tried :

> foreach (QGraphicsItem* currentItem, scene->selectedItems())

But above does not work for multiple selection. It means if I have selected 2 itms from the scene, and now I want to dehighlight both of them, then it always dehighlight 1 item.
I tried to print the value of

> scene->selectedItems().size() => 1

So I want to :

> 1. Dehighlight multiple object.
> 2. To dehighlight 1 object, I do not
>    want to iterate over all scene.

I got some hint:

```
If you want to deselect / dehighlight  all selected items quickly 
then try to use QGraphicsScene::clearselection()
```

How to use `QGraphicsScene::clearselection()` here ?

Comment: Use QtWidgets or QML, you will hardly find anyone caring about the QGraphicsView framework these days.

Comment: @LászlóPapp  Sorry, but I can not take such decision. I will have to continue with `QGraphicsView` framework.

Comment: Why could you not? It is a pain, Qt does not support it anymore and you have not been getting help with QGraphicsView. Who would be so unreasonable to continue under these conditions?

Comment: @LászlóPapp Yes, you are true. Even my last question was unanswered. ( You asked this same question there also  ;) )  Let us hope someone will answer.

Comment: Not just your last answer, but if I check the history on the qgraphicsview tag, you have many unanswered questions.

Comment: @LászlóPapp Have you worked ever on `QGraphicsView`  ?

Comment: Yes, a lot, Plasma was based on it in KDE, and I regret it.

Comment: @LászlóPapp  Can you help me how to use `QGraphicsScene::clearselection()`  in above situation ?

Comment: No, sorry, not going to spend time with a long-dead framework :)

Comment: @LászlóPapp Re. `"Qt does not support [QGraphicsView framework] anymore"`: is that official?  Can you provide a reference/citation?

Comment: Check the git log. The last maintainer have not had more than literally 1-2 commits since 2013 (9 years).